# How to make sublime text see .mod files in different folders?

Tags: fortran, sublimetext3, sublimelinter

In my program I use multiple module files. In order to keep main folder clean I moved all of them in separate folders and made necessary changes to my shell script. Everything was done correctly as now I am able to compile and run the program. Unfortunately, Sublime Text 3 doesn't see .mod files located not in the main folder. On lines like this:

```
use mymodule
```

it says:

> Fatal Error: Can't open module file ‘mymodule.mod’ for reading at (1): No such file or directory

How can I fix this?

Comment: What is your compiler? How are you calling it from the editor?

Comment: @VladimirF, I've added information on build system for Fortran in my question. Compiler - gfortran. Calling from editor specified in "shell_cmd".

Comment: Looks like you need to tell the buildsystem which file depends on which. But I have no idea how to do that for Sublime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Sublime Text go to `Preferences`->`Package Settings`->`SublimeLinter`->`Settings - User`. There in the block `"gfortranfixedform"` or `"gfortranmodern"` (depends on what form you are using) add an argument: `"args": ["-Ipath/to/modfiles"]`, where path/to/modfiles is a directory with your .mod files.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to change the line in config to this:

```
"shell_cmd": "gfortran '${file}' -Ipath/to/module -o '${file_path}/${file_base_name}'"
```

where path/to/module is a directory with your .mod file. (Just a suggestion, don't know anything about Sublime editor.)

Comment: Your idea with some changes works fine for building single module files but, unfortunately, it doesn't solve my problem. With your suggestion I can build .f90 files containing my modules and get desired generated .mod files in correct separate folders. So, Sublime sees everything perfectly while building. But for some reason, all other time it looks for dependencies only in the current folder, it doesn't find them there and it gives me annoying error saying: "no such file". Question is how to make Sublime look for dependencies in other folders.

Comment: This error doesn't affect running the program but it just doesn't let Sublime show me any other errors or warnings as that error is always the 1st one.

Comment: Maybe you add also `-I.` (dot = current directory)

Comment: Now I believe that problem is not about Build Systems at all, but about adding paths/environment variables to some Sublime project configuration file. Unfortunately, I won't be able to try this version until next week. Then I will update the question. Thanks for trying to help!